# How to display last year in simple_form label?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I need to have `<%= Time.now.year - 1 %>` in a simple_form label. How do I do this or something similar like it?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The following code is what it is at the moment. I would like to replace "last year" with some ruby=on-rails syntax.

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :readings do |r| %>
   <%= r.input :amount, label: "Average kWh last year" %>
   <%= r.file_field :meter, class: "primary-button" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does your form code look like right now?

Comment: I added the current code as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
"Average kWh #{1.year.ago.year}"
```

That should do the job